# Progressive column grouping spacing issue

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have four columns of Ident codes corresponding to a single individual with multiple entries.  I need to get a list of all unique Ident codes corresponding to each individual on one line with a comma followed by a space between them. 
I have a VBA to remove the duplicates, but the VBA won't work - I think because the commas don't have a space after them in the final row of Ident code data that I'm asking it to look at.  I feel like there is an easy solution and I'm just not seeing it. I'm VERY new to VBA and moderately good with Excel.

This is the statement I'm using to return the progressive values of codes pertaining to each person, the final row being the culmination of all of their codes in one cell

```
=IF(A12=A11,P11&"," &O12, O12)
```

See the attached file column P - when it gets to four or more codes there's no space after the comma any longer and the VBA duplicate remover doesn't work.

[Sample of my Worksheet

After I get that formula down I should be able to run this VBA to get rid of the duplicates in the line with the culmination of all the codes... I think...

```
Function RemoveDupes2(txt As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String
Dim x
'Updateby20140924
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each x In Split(txt, delim)
        If Trim(x) <> "" And Not .exists(Trim(x)) Then .Add Trim(x), Nothing
    Next
    If .Count > 0 Then RemoveDupes2 = Join(.keys, delim)
End With
End Function
```

I don't know what else to try, there are hundreds of thousands of these that I need to go through

Any help anyone can give me would be amazing and I would be so thankful.  I found the formulas and VBA on this site and modified them to my need, but I think I don't quite understand it enough to modify it correctly.

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════╦═══════════╦════════╦═════════════╦═════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Number ║ First Name ║ MI ║ Last Name ║ Suffix ║ Patient DOB ║ Sex ║ Zip Code ║  Home Phone  ║ Ident Code 1 ║ Ident Code 2 ║ Ident Code 3 ║ Ident Code 4 ║ Service Date ║         Row Groups          ║                                                          Individual Code Set                                                          ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════╬═══════════╬════════╬═════════════╬═════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ G10          ║ T76          ║              ║              ║ 2/5/1995     ║ G10, T76                    ║ G10, T76                                                                                                                              ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ G10          ║ E78.5        ║ D70.6        ║ Q90.28       ║ 2/3/2017     ║ G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28   ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28                                                                                                    ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ B15          ║              ║              ║              ║ 5/7/2017     ║ B15                         ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15                                                                                                ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ B15          ║              ║              ║              ║ 6/5/2015     ║ B15                         ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15,B15                                                                                            ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ I10          ║ K21.0        ║ E03.9        ║ M77.11       ║ 5/5/2015     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11   ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11                                                                                                             ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 3/3/1995     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256                                                                                                     ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 2/8/1978     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                             ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 3/8/2014     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                     ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ M22.58       ║              ║              ║              ║ 6/1/1956     ║ M22.58                      ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58                                                                              ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ Z78.563      ║ N35          ║ Z12.39       ║ J23.5        ║ 5/4/2016     ║ Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5 ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5                                                  ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ E03.9        ║ N35          ║ R19.7        ║ O22.3        ║ 2/2/1998     ║ E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3    ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3                         ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H26.9        ║ Z01.818      ║ B23.356      ║              ║ 3/5/2017     ║ H26.9, Z01.818, B23.356     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3,H26.9, Z01.818, B23.356 ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════╩═══════════╩════════╩═════════════╩═════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝




╔════════╦════════════╦════╦═══════════╦════════╦═════════════╦═════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Number ║ First Name ║ MI ║ Last Name ║ Suffix ║ Patient DOB ║ Sex ║ Zip Code ║  Home Phone  ║ Ident Code 1 ║ Ident Code 2 ║ Ident Code 3 ║ Ident Code 4 ║ Service Date ║         Row Groups          ║                                                          Individual Code Set                                                          ║                                                               VBA                                                                ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════╬═══════════╬════════╬═════════════╬═════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ G10          ║ T76          ║              ║              ║ 2/5/1995     ║ G10, T76                    ║ G10, T76                                                                                                                              ║ G10, T76                                                                                                                         ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ G10          ║ E78.5        ║ D70.6        ║ Q90.28       ║ 2/3/2017     ║ G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28   ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28                                                                                                    ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28                                                                                               ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ B15          ║              ║              ║              ║ 5/7/2017     ║ B15                         ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15                                                                                                ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15                                                                                           ║
║      5 ║ Jane       ║ D  ║ Doe       ║        ║ 1/1/1999    ║ F   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ B15          ║              ║              ║              ║ 6/5/2015     ║ B15                         ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15,B15                                                                                            ║ G10, T76,G10, E78.5, D70.6, Q90.28,B15,B15                                                                                       ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ I10          ║ K21.0        ║ E03.9        ║ M77.11       ║ 5/5/2015     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11   ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11                                                                                                             ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11                                                                                                        ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 3/3/1995     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256                                                                                                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256                                                                                                ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 2/8/1978     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                             ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                        ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H44.256      ║              ║              ║              ║ 3/8/2014     ║ H44.256                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256                                                                                ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ M22.58       ║              ║              ║              ║ 6/1/1956     ║ M22.58                      ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58                                                                              ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58                                                                         ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ Z78.563      ║ N35          ║ Z12.39       ║ J23.5        ║ 5/4/2016     ║ Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5 ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5                                                  ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5                                             ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ E03.9        ║ N35          ║ R19.7        ║ O22.3        ║ 2/2/1998     ║ E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3    ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3                         ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, R19.7, O22.3                         ║
║      2 ║ Bob        ║ L  ║ Man       ║        ║ 5/5/2007    ║ M   ║    44444 ║ 333-333-3333 ║ H26.9        ║ Z01.818      ║ B23.356      ║              ║ 3/5/2017     ║ H26.9, Z01.818, B23.356     ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, N35, R19.7, O22.3,H26.9, Z01.818, B23.356 ║ I10, K21.0, E03.9, M77.11,H44.256,H44.256,H44.256,M22.58,Z78.563, N35, Z12.39, J23.5,E03.9, R19.7, O22.3,H26.9, Z01.818, B23.356 ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════╩═══════════╩════════╩═════════════╩═════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Your worksheet example did not get attached

Comment: I tried to upload an image to help explain this but it won't let me, I'll try again

Comment: It would be better if you could "fake a table" in text, that can be copied/pasted into a worksheet.  Can't do that with an image.

Comment: Ok, don't give up on me... I did make a fake table, and I have it in a worksheet, I'm just trying to figure out how to get it attached to this question... I'm sorry I'm obviously very new here :(  I'm thankful you answered me!

Comment: Try [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table)

Comment: Almost done, I got it to make my table.  I'm going to try to add the link

Comment: Don't add a link -- just copy/paste the results from SS into your original post.

Comment: Copy and paste the Output?  I really can't apologize enough for my ignorance

Comment: Use the MySQL or Unicode Art style output,  NOT the HTML

Comment: Then you use the `Code Sample` button so it will scroll, as I did.

Comment: Your pasted example shows commas after each entry in Column P, even if there are more than four.

Comment: But there are no spaces after the comma once it hits line 3 between Q90.28 and B15

Comment: If you use the comma as the delimiter, your function seems to work OK. Your UDF is trimming the extraneous spaces anyway.

Comment: So maybe the commas aren't the problem then, when I run the VBA on column P it doesn't remove the duplicates, so I thought maybe the comma space issue was throwing it off

Comment: When I put your UDF into column Q, it returned the list originally in column P, without duplicates

Comment: That makes me want to cry a bit, because I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I've been doing this for 2 days

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me Ron, I wish I could send you candy or flowers or something.  I don't know why it won't work for me, it just returns what I added to the original post :(

Comment: Perhaps you can upload a copy of your workbook to some file sharing site,and post the link to it here.

Comment: What's the forumla you're using in column `Q`? You might be using it wrong?

Comment: That's it, it should be `=RemoveDupes2(P2, ",")` ... specify your delimiter bc the default delimiter of your UDF is the space!

Comment: I probably am using it wrong.  I put the VBA in using F11, insert module, and then in Q I just typed =removedups2 which is the name of the thing and it comes up, so I double click it and I thought that would make it work...

Comment: As in my previous comment, specify the delimiter as comma: `=RemoveDupes2(P2, ",")`

Comment: OH MY LANTA I COULD LITERALLY COME THROUGH MY COMPUTER AND HUG YOU.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you both, you don't even understand.  I'll educate myself further before I come back and bother anyone again.  I honestly can not thank you both enough

Comment: @KLM You did not bother anyone, you're welcome anytime and we are glad to help :)